# Locate a bad combination of values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to automate some part on excel for my work, I tried Index and Match but it doesn't provide me what I have in mind and I am quiet confuse what formula should I used.

I have a sheet in excel containing a list of combinations and I have mark "N" on the cell which is a bad combination.

For example, this is the sheet containing the data i want to query:

[image: Source data]

And this is the result I want to achieve:

[image: Data with expected result]

In general I wanted to display the bad combination(N) of Potato(B10), Apple(C10),Orange(D10),Mango(E10),Lemon(F10) on B11 to F10.

For example for Potato(B10), I wanted to display what this the bad combination(N)

Comment: Ah yes, just random data I want to enter for reference.. pls don't mind it. I just renamed it to LIST instead to avoid distraction.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I have Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two FILTER()s the first to return the correct ROW and the second to filter on `N`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$1:$F$1,FILTER($B$2:$F$6,$A$2:$A$6=B10)="N"))
```

Put that in B11 and copy over

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works great. Let me test it on other data and get back to you on the part I need clarification. Thank you.

Comment: The solution was awesome. I have added another scenario on the post, how I should achieve it? thanks for the time.

Comment: @JohnEnglatiera that is not how this forum works.  once you get an answer adding additional needs it not correct.  Instead you mark the answer that answered the first question correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer and then you ask a new question, you can always refer back to this one to help the readers on the second get a better understanding.  But by changing the question you open up my answer for down votes.

Comment: Sounds good, noted Scott. I have marked your response as an answer