# Locate a bad combination of values in Excel with more refinements

Tags: microsoft-excel

I recently asked a question and it was answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1737722/167207).

I have a follow up question for a different scenario using same references.

This is what I am trying to achieve.
I want to see if `ORANGE`/`MANGO`/`LEMON` is a bad combination of `POTATO` from the source data in A6-F6
Then check it against cell B28-F28 if its present, then return a value `EXIST`.

[image: scene 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, see if below solution helps. It uses OFFSET which is not very efficient but for small data it should be ok.

Sample data as shown in below screenshot.

Output table at A12:F13.

In B13 put the following formula and drag it across.

```
=IF(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH($A$12,$A$1:$A$6,0)):OFFSET(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH($A$12,$A$1:$A$6,0)),0,COLUMNS($B$1:$F$1)) INDEX($A$1:$F$1,MATCH(B$12,$A$1:$F$1,0)):OFFSET(INDEX($A$1:$F$1,MATCH(B$12,$A$1:$F$1,0)),ROWS($A$2:$A$6),0)="N","EXIST","")
```

[image]

Note the two values for COLUMN offset & ROW offset.

```
COLUMNS($B$1:$F$1)

ROWS($A$2:$A$6)
```

The formula uses INDEX to return a cell reference and intersect operator as space to get the intersection of two ranges.

Shorter version of formula using FILTER & LET Functions available in Office 365 or 2021 is

```
=LET(a,INDEX($A$1:$F$1,MATCH(B$12,$A$1:$F$1,0)),IF(FILTER(a:OFFSET(a,ROWS($A$2:$A$6),0),$A$1:$A$6=$A$12)="N","EXIST",""))
```

Comment: oh yeah!!!! that actually works.. much appreciated. When you say OFFSET is not very efficient, I wanted to confirm does that affect the accuracy of the result?

Comment: OFFSET is volatile meaning it will recalculate every time worksheet changes even if those specific  cells don't. So while the result is not affected, on large datasets it can slow down the sheet.

Comment: got it, thank you.